# If f is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable at all points except some point in (a,b), prove the following

Tags: real-analysis

If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and differentiable on all points $(a,b)$ except some $c \in (a,b)$ and $\lim_{x\to c} f'(x)$ exists, show that $f'(c)$ exists and tat $f'$ is continuous at c.

Comment: What is $f'(c)$ if $f$ is not differentiable at $c$?

Comment: @mechanodroid The point is to show it is differentiable at $c$ and that the rest follows.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(\eta_{x})$ for some $\eta_{x}$ lies in between $c$ and $x$, here $x\ne c$, take $x\rightarrow c$, as $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f'(x)=L$ exists, then $f'(\eta_{x})\rightarrow L$, which shows also that $f'(c)$ exists and $f'(c)=L$. The continuity of $f'$ at $x=c$ is then clear.

The word in between means $\eta_{x}\ne x$ and also $\eta_{x}\ne c$, this is done by Mean Value Theorem, in particular, $\eta_{x}\ne c$, so there is no problem in using $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f'(x)$.

To be precise, let $\epsilon>0$ and find some $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<|u-c|<\delta$ we have $\left|f'(u)-L\right|<\epsilon$. For any $x$ with $0<|x-c|<\delta$, there exists some $\eta_{x}$ lies in between $x$ and $c$ such that $\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(\eta_{x})$, such $\eta_{x}$ also satisfies $0<|\eta_{x}-c|<\delta$, take $u=\eta_{x}$ and we have $\left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-L\right|=|f'(\eta_{x})-L|<\epsilon$. So $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=L$, in other words, $f'(c)=L$.

Comment: I dont see how the MVT showed the existence of the limit as x approaches c of f'(x). Furthermore, how did you deduce that f'(c) exists from that and that it also equals L?

Comment: I have edited, I think it works now. Note that $\eta_{x}=(1-t)c+tx$ for some $0<t<1$ which depended on $x$, so $|\eta_{x}-c|=t|x-c|<t\delta<\delta$.