# What can we say about differentiability of $f$ at $c$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

$a < c < b$ ; $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $ a , b , c \in \mathbb{R}$

Assume that $f$ is differentiable at every point of 
 $(a,b)\setminus \{c \}$ and $f^{'}$ has a limit at $c$ then what can we say about differentiability and continuity of $f$ at $c$ ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please for the love of all that is good, do not keep escaping your $\rm\LaTeX$ like that. You don't need to do `$a$ < $b$`, etc. You can simply write `$a<b$` for $a<b$. Furthermore, to get $\setminus$ for set difference, do \setminus, and for brackets in $\rm\LaTeX$, do \{ and \}.

Comment: Thank you Cameron!

Comment: The [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) demonstrates that $f$ need not be continuous (or differentiable) at $c=0$.

Comment: If you *assume* $f$ to be continuous at $c$ then it is also differentiable: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2511227

Comment: But I've problem, what can we conclude from the fact that limit of $f^{'}$  at $c$ exists [Martin R](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42969/martin-r) !?

Comment: @Alfha: Nothing. See the example of the sign function given above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the hypotheses of the question have nothing to do with the value of $f(c)$: if you change the value of $f(c)$ but otherwise leave $f$ the same, then $f$ will still be differentiable on $(a,b)\setminus \{c\}$ and $f'$ will still have a limit at $c$.  But there is at most one value of $f(c)$ that will make $f$ continuous at $c$ (namely the limit of $f$ at $c$, if it exists), so you can choose $f(c)$ such that $f$ is not continuous at $c$ (and hence not differentiable either).  So, for instance, you can get a counterexample by starting with any differentiable function on all of $(a,b)$ and then changing the value of $f(c)$.

Comment: We define $f(x) = x^2 \  \forall x\in(-1,1) \setminus \{0\}$ and $$f(0) = 4$$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f^{'}(x)$ doesn't exist but according to your answer it should exist!

Comment: Why do you say the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: As value of $f^{'}$ at zero makes no sense!

Comment: We're talking about the limit, not the value.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f : (-a,a) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is $x^2+2$ for $x<0$ and $-x^2-2$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then $f$ is differentiable on $(-a,a) / \{0\}$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)=0$. But $f$ is not continuous (and so differentiable) on $0$.