# How can I prove this differentiability question?

Tags: calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be continuous, and differentiable at every point $x\in\mathbb R - \lbrace c\rbrace$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$. If $\,\,\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)\,\,$ exists, then $f$ is differentiable at $x = c$ with $f'(c) = \lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$.

I want to know how to prove that the sentence above is true.

Comment: Write out the sentence in MathJax, please....

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: The sentence “enter image description here” does not make any claims or assertions and hence cannot be viewed as either true or false.

Comment: Note that the linked post doesn't answer the question (none of the answers assume continuity at $x=c$), but [the post linked by Martin R in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511227/if-f-is-continuous-on-a-b-and-differentiable-at-all-points-except-some-point-i) does.